# I want to change alias about python but I don't khow how

Tags: linux-mint

I want to be able to start python3.7.0 if I enter python at the terminal, but I do not know how. If you enter Python as terminal now, python 2.7.6 will be launched.

I think I could solve the problem by changing the alias setting, but I did not know how to change it.

The contents of the corresponding file were [PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:usr/sbin:usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"]. How do I change this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace your Python 2 with your Python 3 executable on your environment variables. If on Windows, click the search button on your task bar and type environment variables and replace all the Python 2 paths with Python 3 ones.
In Linux Mint, try the below:
Open /etc/environment as root with a text editor:

> sudo gedit /etc/environment

Change the desired variable (the one with Python 2) in the text file separated by colon, save, logout, login - and it is permanently and globally changed.

Comment: How do I change environment variables with linuxmint?　I know that you can see path information in command: printenv PATH.